# Can't change dk_toggle width from dropkick plugin

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using dropkick jQuery plugin

I know, that dk_toggle has default width: 220px:

```
      <a class="dk_toggle" style="width: 220px; ">(from Google console)
```

My html in my view:

```
     <select name="country" class="default" tabindex="2">
          <option value="EN">English</option>
          <option value="IS">Israeli</option>
          <option value="UA">Ukrainian</option>
        </select>
```

But I want to change it in my css file:

```
 .dk_toggle {
 height: 15px;
 width: 245px;
}
```

It isn't changing. So HOW I should change it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your javascript file add

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dk_toggle').css('width','220px');
})
```

Comment: won't this affect all selects?

Comment: No selects. Just the ones with that class.

Answer (score 2):

First, set an ID to your select:

```
 <select id="my_select" name="country" class="default" tabindex="2">
      <option value="EN">English</option>
      <option value="IS">Israeli</option>
      <option value="UA">Ukrainian</option>
 </select>
```

Then set a CSS for this ID:

```
#my_select{
  width: 200px;
}
```

I just tested it, and probably a cleaner way to do it.